# Objective-C Data Structure for Categorizing Items

Tags: objective-c, data-structures

I'm new to  objective-c and I'm looking for a good data structure to allow for the categorization of items. Let's say I wanted to categorize types of food. The categories are meat, fruit, and vegetables. When a user inputs "apple" then I want to know that the apple belongs to the fruit category. In addition, these categories need to be mutable. So, if a user inputs an unknown food then they can assign it to a category and the category will be updated to remember this new type of food.

I have looked at using an [NSMutableArray](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/). My thinking goes that I would have an array for each category of food, and the elements of the array would be all the foods that fall in that category. I would then just search each array until I found a match.

The categories won't be too massive (< ~5,000 items in each), but large enough that I would like to have them sorted and take other considerations to allow for quick searching.

What are some good data structures to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-C provides 3 data structures which can be useful for your purpose, `NSArray`, [`NSSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/) and [`NSDictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/). These come also in the mutable flavour and `NSSet` offers also the [`NSOrderedSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSOrderedSet_Class/) subclass which can manage ordering.

What you should use depends on which kind of operations you are going to do mostly with your data:

- you could have an `NSMutableSet` member for each food instance if you plan to assign multiple categories per element.
- you could have a `NSMutableArray` of `NSMutableSet` instances, one per category and add the food to the specific `NSMutableSet`
- you could have a `NSMutableDictionary` which maps each food to its category

But still it depends if you need fast lookup in one direction or in the other. Just think about that `NSSet` and `NSDictionary` provide fast lookup (so it's efficient to check if an element is contained in a `NSSet` or getting the value mapped to a specific key of a `NSDictionary`)

Comment: Ah, just what I was looking for! Thank you.